# Onclick button create component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello Guys i have code that onclick to checkbox loop through the array and add it to component with class active and text with value of checkbox,so now i need to implement when button clicked only then to add values to component.I am new to vue js so get some problems right now.So I Will appreciate any help that will be here.

```js
Vue.component('picked-filter', {
  template: `<div class="active">{{ checked }}</div>`,
  props: ['checked']
})



new Vue({
  el: '#filter',
  data() {
    return {
      brands: [
        {
          brandName: 'Acer',
          id: 1,
        }, 
        {
          brandName: 'Asus',
          id: 2,
        }, 
        {
          brandName: 'Lenovo',
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          brandName: 'Dell',
          id: 4,
        }
      ],
      checkedItems: [],
      isShowing: false,
      checkedFilter:true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
 <div id="filter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="filter-container">
      <div class="top-filters">
        <div class="top-filters-picked">
          <picked-filter
          v-for="checked in checkedItems"
          v-bind:key="checked.id"
          v-bind:checked="checked"
          ></picked-filter>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row items">
      <div class="side-bar col-lg-3 col-md-0">
        <div class="filters">
          <div class="filterRes">
            <div class="container-widgets">
              <div class="container-header" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                <h3 class="collapse-title">Savings & Stock</h3>
                <i id="rotation" class="fa fa-angle-down rotate"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="container-section">
                <div class="brands-text">
                  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <ul id="filters">
                      <li  v-for="(product,index) in brands"  >
                        <input :value="product.brandName" id="product.brandName" v-model="checkedItems" class="filter-values" name="check" type="checkbox" :id="index" />
                        <label  class="category-label" :for="index" >{{product.brandName}}</label>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="filter">
              <button class="button-filter">Change</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></scrFipt>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```